# PostgreSQL Query to search multiple words in multiple table columns storing PII Data

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

Is there an efficient way to search multiple words, i mean like 50 words occurring in table fields containing PII Data

As of now i have this query

```
 SELECT reporter FROM case_detail cd WHERE (cd.reporter)::text IN (‘ID_ISSUE_PLACE’,‘USER_NAME’,‘STATE’,‘PROOFTYPE_1’,‘ID_EXPIRES_ALLOWED’,‘KIN_MIDDLENAME’,‘EMAIL’,‘GENDER’,‘COUNTRY’,‘PROOFTYPE_2’,‘RESIDENCE_COUNTRY’,‘KIN_AGE’,‘ID_TYPE’,‘CONTACT_PERSON’,‘BIRTHPLACE’,‘PROOFTYPE_3’,‘NATIONALITY’,‘KIN_CONTACTNUMBER’,‘ID_NO’,‘CONTACT_NO’,‘NOMINATION_DETAIL’,‘MIDDLE_NAME’,‘EMPLOYER_NAME’,‘KIN_NATIONALITY’,‘SSN’,‘MSISDN’,‘IMSI’,‘LAST_NAME’,‘DOB’,‘POSTAL_CODE’,‘KIN_NATIONALITYNO’,‘ADDRESS1’,‘DIST_MSISDN’,‘ID_ISSUE_DATE’,‘REFERENCEID’,‘KIN_RELATIONSHIP’,‘ADDRESS2’,‘RET_MSISDN’,‘ID_ISSUE_COUNTRY’,‘REGION’,‘SOURCE_OF_INCOME’,‘CITY’,‘BUSINESS_NAME’,‘ID_EXPIRY_DATE’,‘KIN_FIRSTNAME’,‘ORGANIZATION_NAME’,‘PROOFID_1’,‘PROOFID_2’,'PROOFID_3’,'KIN_LASTNAME’,‘Wallet')
```

Which is throwing SQL Syntax error

We needed to encrypt data contained in such table fields

any help will be appreciated

```
   SELECT reporter FROM case_detail cd WHERE (cd.reporter)::text IN (‘ID_ISSUE_PLACE’,‘USER_NAME’,‘STATE’,‘PROOFTYPE_1’,‘ID_EXPIRES_ALLOWED’,‘KIN_MIDDLENAME’,‘EMAIL’,‘GENDER’,‘COUNTRY’,‘PROOFTYPE_2’,‘RESIDENCE_COUNTRY’,‘KIN_AGE’,‘ID_TYPE’,‘CONTACT_PERSON’,‘BIRTHPLACE’,‘PROOFTYPE_3’,‘NATIONALITY’,‘KIN_CONTACTNUMBER’,‘ID_NO’,‘CONTACT_NO’,‘NOMINATION_DETAIL’,‘MIDDLE_NAME’,‘EMPLOYER_NAME’,‘KIN_NATIONALITY’,‘SSN’,‘MSISDN’,‘IMSI’,‘LAST_NAME’,‘DOB’,‘POSTAL_CODE’,‘KIN_NATIONALITYNO’,‘ADDRESS1’,‘DIST_MSISDN’,‘ID_ISSUE_DATE’,‘REFERENCEID’,‘KIN_RELATIONSHIP’,‘ADDRESS2’,‘RET_MSISDN’,‘ID_ISSUE_COUNTRY’,‘REGION’,‘SOURCE_OF_INCOME’,‘CITY’,‘BUSINESS_NAME’,‘ID_EXPIRY_DATE’,‘KIN_FIRSTNAME’,‘ORGANIZATION_NAME’,‘PROOFID_1’,‘PROOFID_2’,'PROOFID_3’,'KIN_LASTNAME’,‘Wallet')
```

**AND THIS ASWELL**

```
SELECT reporter FROM case_detail WHERE reporter CONTAINS 'ID_ISSUE_PLACE And USER_NAME And STATE And PROOFTYPE_1 And ID_EXPIRES_ALLOWED And KIN_MIDDLENAME And EMAIL And GENDER And COUNTRY And PROOFTYPE_2 And RESIDENCE_COUNTRY And KIN_AGE And ID_TYPE And CONTACT_PERSON And BIRTHPLACE And PROOFTYPE_3 And NATIONALITY And KIN_CONTACTNUMBER And ID_NO And CONTACT_NO And NOMINATION_DETAIL And MIDDLE_NAME And EMPLOYER_NAME And KIN_NATIONALITY And SSN And MSISDN And IMSI And LAST_NAME And DOB And POSTAL_CODE And KIN_NATIONALITYNO And ADDRESS1 And DIST_MSISDN And ID_ISSUE_DATE And REFERENCEID And KIN_RELATIONSHIP And ADDRESS2 And RET_MSISDN And ID_ISSUE_COUNTRY And REGION And SOURCE_OF_INCOME And CITY And BUSINESS_NAME And ID_EXPIRY_DATE And KIN_FIRSTNAME And ORGANIZATION_NAME And PROOFID_1 And PROOFID_2 And PROOFID_3 And KIN_LASTNAME And Wallet';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store reporter as a tsvector, which is effectively turns the text into an indexable array of words. A separate auto generated tsvector column can be added to the table using the following query.

```
ALTER TABLE case_detail ADD COLUMN
text_search tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS to_tsvector('english', reporter);
```

You can then search for relevant cases using the @@ contains operator and an appropriate tsquery.

```
SELECT reporter
FROM case_detail cd
WHERE cd.text_search @@ to_tsquery('word1 & word2 & ... & wordn');
```

You can even add a GIN index to the table to improve the performance of the text search for large tables.

```
CREATE INDEX case_detail_text_search_idx ON case_detail USING GIN (text_search);
```

However one thing you should be aware of is that since underscores aren't part of regular words postgres will assume the text separated by the underscores are each their own word so 'USER_NAME' and 'USER' & 'NAME' are treated identically. If the text containing underscores is a must and your requirements for text search is limited to a set of keywords containing another set of keywords then storing the text as an text array is also possible. Simply replace to_tsvector('english', reporter) with regexp_split_to_array(reporter, '\s+') when creating the generated column, use @> ['word1, 'word2', ...] for the select instead and a GIN index can be created on the text[] type just the same as a tsvector.